# Can't "dotnet restore" since upgrading to Win10 1803, fails with error MSB4019, even on a blank project

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, windows-10

I've been getting frustrated with dependency problems since upgrading to Fall Creators, so I started with a fresh Windows 10 1709 image on my computer from our IT department, reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 from scratch with the UWP workload and the 16299 SDK. I made a blank UWP app, opened the Package Manager Console and ran "dotnet restore", and got the following error:

```
C:\Users\username\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.csproj(137,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I searched my C: drive and found that those files are stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\

---

**EDIT:**

I should have asked about my original problem instead of the problem I had when trying to fix my problem. I've really confused things here.

My app is a UWP app that uses EF Core, so I have a solution with two projects, just like Microsoft recommends. One is a library with the data models, the other is the UWP app.

When I upgraded to Windows 1803 and Visual Studio 2017, I could no longer compile my app. Visual Studio would give the error `The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found`

I also couldn't do a migration without errors, which is what precipitated my question here. I thought something was wrong with my .NET Core SDK installation, so I made a blank app to test.

Using your answer here (and [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started), I determined that even though my data model project worked as a .NET Core Class Library in .NET Core 1.x, it needed to be a .NET Standard Class Library in .NET Core 2.x.

So I can compile my app and do migrations now, but I have to manually edit my .csproj file in between those things, as they don't both work with the same TargetFramework(s) setting. But I will make a separate question about that, because it is unrelated to my stupidity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, because dotnet CLI only supports NETCore projects, It does not support UWP project.json or packages.config projects. [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6022#issuecomment-286618978)

If you add a new .NET Core Class Library project to the solution, then run `dotnet restore`, it can work as expected.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5846) in `dotnet` GitHub project which reports exactly the same symptom, and its status is still open.

**Did you meant to run `NuGet restore`, not `dotnet restore`??**

Comment: I edited my question for clarity, but my question is not what I think it was, so I am going to make a separate question for that.

Comment: You did help me figure this out though. I would not have gotten it without your answer. Thank you for finding my simple mistake.

Comment: Hi, I read my post again last night and found I was giving a wrong url for the link. Sorry it might had confused you a little, see my edit.